# Get active item from an array inside the Redux state

Tags: redux, immutability, react-redux

I want to create a draft system with a React/Redux app.

My drafts are stored inside an array reduced by Redux. I render my drafts inside a React component. When I click an item, the clicked item should be marked as active and the draft gets loaded.

The problem is, that I don't know how to get current active array item from the Redux state, in a convenient way.

What I have done so far (minified, no containers etc):

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const drafts = (state = [{ title: '' }], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_NEW_DRAFT':
      return [{ title: '' }, ...state];

    case 'ACTIVATE_DRAFT':
      // This is where I need help

    case 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_DRAFT':
      // This is where I need help

    default:
      return state;
  }
});

const store = createStore(drafts);

const drafts = store.getState().drafts;
const draft = drafts[0]; // Maybe something like this? Looks ugly to me

const createDraft = () => store.dispatch({
  type: 'CREATE_NEW_DRAFT',
});

const activateDraft = draft => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  store.dispatch({
    draft,
    type: 'ACTIVATE_DRAFT',
  });
};

const updateDraft = e => store.dispatch({
  title: e.target.value,
  type: 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_DRAFT',
});

export default () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {drafts.map((element, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          <a onClick={activateDraft(element)}>element.title</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <button type="button" onClick={createDraft}>Create</button>
    <input type="text" value={draft.title} onChange={updateDraft} />
  </div>
);
```

So, how do I know which item is the active one? How do I "activate" an item? One solution is a "active" pointer in the state, but it doesn't feel very comfortable to handle.

Thank you!

Comment: always keep active element in separate prop, this will make your life lot easier,  so next time when someone activates a draft just copy its object to activeDraft prop

Comment: How would you update the drafts array when the activeDraft property changes?

Comment: if you want to update the array at the sametime then store the current selected index in activeDraft instead of object.

Comment: Hm, I come around this idea, too. I will try it, thank you!

Comment: Ok, it works now with array slicing! I will post an answer in a second. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer for this question. I stored the activeDraft pointer in a additional state property, so that I can fetch the activeDraft by `state.drafts[state.active]`.

I update the active draft with this case inside my reducer:

```
case 'UPDATE_DRAFT':
  return [
    ...state.slice(0, action.active),
    Object.assign({}, state[action.active], action.draft),
    ...state.slice(action.active + 1),
  ];
```

`action.active` is the new state property that I pass to my component to do this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={updateDraft(state.active)} />
```

The draft activation works in the same way.

Thanks to [abhirathore2006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1785635/abhirathore2006)!